# Do people in USA need official permission to demonstrate?

Tags: united-states, constitution

In some countries, people who want to demonstrate need to get official permission from the Ministry of Home Affairs in advance. In order to get that, they have to elaborate their reason and specify the path they want to march through. If they can get the permission, then their demonstration is lawful. Otherwise, it is recognized as an illegal action, and thus they might face penalty.

Now the question is: do people or groups who want to demonstrate in the US need to get official permission? Do they have to pass a similar procedure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the most part no.  If you have a location that is amenable to have a gathering you do not need to get permission for the group to demonstrate.  The [ACLU has a great summary](http://www.aclupa.org/issues/freespeech/kyrataprotest.htm) of how free speech and the right to assemble work in the USA.

However if you want to do so in a public space then you may (and most likely do) need a permit from the local (Usually city or county) government to use that public space for your demonstration.  In [general speech is protected](http://sex.ncu.edu.tw/members/Ho/study/2008fall_training/free_speech_rights.pdf) so **the permit issuer must have a very compelling reason to deny a group a permit.**  That the agency does not want your group demonstrating is not enough to deny the permit with a very few exception like those groups that have been found to be criminal organizations through [the RICO act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racketeer_Influenced_and_Corrupt_Organizations_Act), or your group has a standing injunction from the courts that prevents them from demonstrating in the jurisdiction.

[The occupy Blog put it this way](http://occupypeace.blogspot.com/2011/10/permits-for-protest-marches.html):

> Yes, generally you cannot protest outside of a person's house. (This
>   can be different for a public official.  Keep in mind that if the
>   house is located in a residential area, there can be strict limits on
>   noise, parking, etc. ) There may be limits on protesting outside of
>   someone's place of business.  Harassment is not a protected form of
>   speech, so it depends on what your protest is about and why you would
>   be in front of someone's house.  Also, many locations limit or
>   prohibit protesting outside a medical facility.   Many publicly-owned
>   schools, especially grammar and high schools, do not allow protesters
>   on the property.  There may be limits in parks; most cities require a
>   permit to hold a protest in a park if the group has more than a given
>   number of participants.  Common numbers are 25 or 50.  Check the
>   municipal law.  Most parks contain protest activity to certain
>   locations.  Most parks also limit or prohibit the use of sound
>   amplifying devices, such as amplifiers or megaphones. You need to
>   check the local laws and the rules regulating a place.  If you plan to
>   hold a protest in such a place, you would be wise to consult with a
>   lawyer first.

Comment: As a note, **some** of the restrictions have environmental concerns as reasons (e.g. parks) and not political or even public safety ones.

Comment: @DVK - They can also deny it based on the needs of local businesses.  But it needs to be a compelling reason.  It is easier to get a permit to demonstrate for a few hours than a few days.  It is also important to note that (Like in the case of OWS) the organizers are the ones bound to the permit, the law has generally held up the rights of the protesters so long as they stay peaceful and do not destroy too much.  The organizers can be fined and possibly even jailed, but the protesters are usually protected by the constitution.

Comment: I was referring more to pre-established general limitations/rules that apply permanently, not to specific per-demonstration permits.

Comment: It seems that there is no difference from what is the case in the jurisdiction of the questioner. It is obvious that the question was about public space rather than private property.

Comment: @Anixx - It is not at all clear.  The restriction is not on the demonstration but rather on the use of public spaces to do so.  It can come down to a distinction with out a difference but I have done my best to explain that.

Comment: @Chad I think there is no restriction in any country about demonstrations in private property. I also doubt that such meeting can be called a "demonstration".

Comment: @Anixx - Really? Try protesting on private property in Iran, Saudi Arabia, China, or North Korea.  Even try protesting the Royal Family in England.

Comment: @Chad Actually I do not imagine how one can do "protesting" on a private property.

Comment: @Anixx - There is lots of open space on many buildings.  It is possible a building owner or manager could give you permission to protest from their courtyard... that also happens to be right across the street/next door too, the abortion clinic you are wanting to protest.  Just for an example.  I think anything further along this line would be discussion that is better done in [chat]

Comment: Well I specifically meant public demonstration in public areas, including parks, streets, squares etc. In Iran, you need to get permission in advance. You have to explain the reason behind the protest, the path you want to march and the number of people will attend. The same procedure should be passed even if you want to assemble without marching. Anyway, the answers and comments were useful. Thanks.